# Does changing the order of sigma notation matter?

Tags: summation

Can you change the order of summation like this and play around? If no, then what does it change?

$$ \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=a}^{b} \sum\limits_{j=p}^{q} f(i) g(j) =\sum\limits_{j=p}^{q} \sum\limits_{i=a}^{b} f(i) g(j)=\sum\limits_{i=a}^{b} f(i) \sum\limits_{j=p}^{q} g(j)$$

I'm guessing yes, but just to be safe, I'm asking the question.

And can I do the same with,

$$ \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=a}^{b} \sum\limits_{j=p}^{q} f(i,j)$$

Comment: Totally fine. Try to list them in a table, or a grid. Then add them line by line or column by column.

Comment: Your changes are fine.  Of course we need ot note that none of $a,b,p,q$ involves $i,j$.  For example, your simple changes do not work on $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \sum\limits_{j=i}^{n} f(i) g(j)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In *finite* sums we can freely change the order of summation. We have
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=a}^{b}}&\color{blue}{ \sum_{j=p}^{q} f(i) g(j)}\\
> &=f(a)g(p)+f(a)g(p+1)+\cdots f(a)g(q)\\
> &\qquad+f(a+1)g(p)+f(a+1)g(p+1)+\cdots+f(a+1)g(q)\\
> &\qquad\ \ \vdots\\
> &\qquad+f(b)g(p)+f(b)g(p+1)+\cdots f(b)g(q)\tag{1}\\
> &=\color{blue}{\sum_{j=p}^{q}\sum_{i=a}^{b} f(i) g(j)}\\
> &=f(a)g(p)+f(a+1)g(p)+\cdots+f(b)g(p)\\
> &\qquad+f(a)g(p+1)+f(a+1)g(p+1)+\cdots+f(b)g(p+1)\\
> &\qquad\ \ \vdots\\
> &\qquad+f(a)g(q)+f(a+1)g(q)+\cdots+f(b)g(q)\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{i=a}^{b}f(i) \sum_{j=p}^{q} g(j)}\\
> &=f(a)\left(g(p)+g(p+1)+\cdots+g(q)\right)\\
> &\qquad+f(a+1)\left(g(p)+g(p+1)+\cdots+g(q)\right)\\
> &\qquad\ \ \vdots\\
> &\qquad+f(b)\left(g(p)+g(p+1)+\cdots+g(q)\right)\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}

Note that (1), (2) and (3) are the same since we can go from one to the other by applying a **finite** number of times the laws of *associativity*, *commutativity* of addition and multiplication as well as the law of distributivity.

Analogously we can apply these laws to the more general double sum $\sum_{i=a}^{b} \sum_{j=p}^{q} f(i,j)$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, just write down a matrix $A$ with entries $a_{i,j} = f(i)g(j)$. Then you can see that sumation of entries over all rows is the same as the sumation over all columns.

Comment: I've edited the question, I accidentally pressed submit without completing the question

Comment: It doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Just lemme know, am I doing it the right way or not, $ \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=a}^{b} \sum\limits_{j=p}^{q} f(i,j) = \sum\limits_{i=a}^{b} \left( f(i,p) + f(i, p+1) + \cdots + f(i,q) \right) $ right? Now I have to substitute the values of $i$ from $a$ to $b$ in "each" of those $f(i,...)$ right? So in total I'll have $\left(b-a+1\right) \cdot \left(q-p+1 \right)$ terms? Right?

Comment: To the proposer: Yes yes yes. But don't do this stuff with sums of $infinite$ sequences unless are the terms are all non-negative (or all non-positive) or you might end up with nonsense.